# c++ set monitor timeout on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, screen, power-management

I was wondering if there's a way to enable or disable monitor/screen timeout from a C++ program on a global scale? (I have one catch though, it must be backward compatible with Windows XP SP3.)

I'm talking about this global setting:

[image: Windows 8 screenshot]

of this one for XP:

[image: XP screenshot]

Comment: If you want to programatically change that setting... you really shouldn't do that. It's very user-unfriendly. If you just want to stop the display from sleeping while your program runs here's a sort of similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463813/programmatically-prevent-windows-screensaver-from-starting.

Comment: Yeah I heard about it, unfortunately most of those APIs like SetThreadExecutionState are very finicky. In my experience, specifying ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED has absolutely no effect.

Comment: I think I got it: CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyAc), and use SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY::VideoTimeout

Comment: Then you should post that as an answer and accept it, otherwise the question appears unanswered and won't benefit those in the future with the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who's interested, here's how to fix this:

Call CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyAc) API to get or set the display timeout value, and use SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY::VideoTimeout member.

Answer (score 1):

A complete sample:

```
bool applyVideoTimeout(DWORD newtimeOut)
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY powerPolicy;
    DWORD ret;
    DWORD size = sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY);

    ret = CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyAc, nullptr, 0, &powerPolicy, size);

    if ((ret != ERROR_SUCCESS) || (size != sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    powerPolicy.VideoTimeout = newtimeOut
    ret = CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyAc, &powerPolicy, size, nullptr, 0);

    if ((ret != ERROR_SUCCESS))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```