# Powershell ISE -MouseclickEvent

Tags: mouseclick-event, powershell-ise

What are the steps in Powershell ISE to automate a click activity. I would appreciate the efforts to guide me from starting.

I tried using it sendkeys method and finding alternate to mouse click event but did not succeed.

Comment: You can test this :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15847232/608772

Comment: Actually I have a desktop application where a button is present and using powershell i want to click that button.How can it be achieved